Fourier Transform of product of sinc function and its raised powers
Is it possible to find the fourier transform of $$\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^3$$ and $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} $$

Have you tried? Where are you stuck?
For the first one, you can use the convolution theorem: $$\mathcal{F}{f(x)g(x)} = \mathcal{F}{f(x)} * \mathcal{F}{g(x)}$$ where $*$ is the convolution operator.

In the second example you mean $\textrm{sinc}(x^2)$ or $(\textrm{sinc}(x))^2$ ($\textrm{sinc}(x) \triangleq\sin(x)/x$). Note that Fourier transform of a composition of two functions is not as easy as Fourier trabsform of a convolution of two functions.

To attack this problem, the following properties of the Fourier transfom come in handy:

Convolution (as @Jdip mentioned)

$$
\mathcal{F}\{(f * g)(t)\}(\xi) = \mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi)\mathcal{F}\{g\}(\xi)
$$

Duality

$$
\mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}(\xi)\}(t) = f(-t)
$$
You also need to know the convolution of the rect function with itself.


Find the fourier transform of $\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)^3$:

$\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)^3$  is the cube of the sinc function. It can use the convolution property of the Fourier transform. In addition, the Fourier transform of the sinc function is a rectangular function.

Find the fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} $:

This can also use the convolution property of the Fourier transform, but $\mathcal{F} \left( \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} \right)$ is not a standard Fourier transform form. This may need to analyze its properties and behavior by relating it to known transforms and approximation techniques.
